# Default text color in an Excel document

Tags: excel, epplus

I created an Excel document with some c# code (see below, but this code is not part of my question).

- The color of the text in cell "A2" is white.
- If i choose 'Format Cells' on "A2" is shows that this cell has Color: 'Automatic'.
- The (commented line) `sheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "test";` does create a black piece of text 'test'.

[image]

Where in Excel (2013) can i change the color of this cell, in such a way that my next created document has a correct (=black) text color on this link?

The file [myWorkbook.xlsx](https://gofile.io/d/dmDHnT) is available (if needed)

C# code:

```
  using OfficeOpenXml;
  using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
  public static void CreateExcelDoc()
  {
       if (File.Exists(@"d:\temp\myWorkbook.xlsx")) { File.Delete(@"d:\temp\myWorkbook.xlsx"); }
       var file = new FileInfo(@"d:\temp\myWorkbook.xlsx");
       using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
       {
           var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
           sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! ";
           sheet.Cells["A1"].Style.WrapText = true;
           sheet.Cells["A1"].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
           sheet.Column(1).Width = 80;

           sheet.Cells[2, 1].Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink("http://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
           //sheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "test";
           sheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "test";

           // Save to file
           package.Save();
       }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You never assign a text color in the code snippet you provided. And if the color is in the xlsx file, you always delete it before using it so the text color can never be white.

Comment: What do you mean by: "you always delete it before using it"?   And, yes, i thought that it never would be white but it seems to be white .  I am suspecting some (changed) default setting in Excel. Resetting Excel to a default (using [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)) did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the fact that there is no text in cell "A2", adding a text, solving my own question:

```
sheet.Cells[2, 1].Hyperlink = 
   new ExcelHyperLink("http://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute) 
         { Display="Google" };
```